# function organize list not working in firefox

Tags: javascript, html

This function organize list, not organized in alphabetical order: ascending/descending in Firefox and Internet Explorer.
In google chrome and Edge is working.

Here is code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

window.onload = function () {
    var desc = false;
    document.getElementById("Order").onclick = function () {
        sortUnorderedList("PostList", desc);
        desc = !desc;
        return false;
    }
}

function compareText(a1, a2) {
    var t1 = a1.innerText,
        t2 = a2.innerText;
    return t1 > t2 ? 1 : (t1 < t2 ? -1 : 0);
}

function sortUnorderedList(ul, sortDescending) {
    if (typeof ul == "string") {
        ul = document.getElementById(ul);
    }

    var lis = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
    var vals = [];

    for (var i = 0, l = lis.length; i < l; i++) {
        vals.push(lis[i]);
    }

    vals.sort(compareText);

    if (sortDescending) {
        vals.reverse();
    }

    ul.innerHTML = '';
    for (var i = 0, l = vals.length; i < l; i++) {
        ul.appendChild(vals[i]);
    }
}

</script>
```

Comment: What doesn't seem to be working? Is there an error in the console? It runs but doesn't do what you expect?

Comment: Are you sure click-handler not working? Maybe your filter has problem?

Comment: Works fine according to this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/t1pm81sg/ How is it not working? Any exceptions? Or is the handler not fired? Have you added a `console.log()` right at the start of your handler before any other code runs to see if its actually fired?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```js
document.getElementById("hello").onclick = talk;
function talk() 
{
    alert('It works!');
}
```

```html
<a id="hello">Click me!</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be right. Is your element ID right? Check if you have more then one element using the same ID also. If you can, post you HTML code.

Answer (score 0):

It's bad if you use code of unknown source, you might even get in trouble with copyrights! Here is a simplified version (No, I won't apologize for the use of Bubble-sort!) that should be easy to follow.

**Edited** on request of OP to add an example of deep copying

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<script type="text/javascript">
// as shown in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3066427/copy-all-childnodes-to-an-other-element-in-javascript-native-way
function copyElements (dst,src){
  while (src.hasChildNodes()) {
    dst.appendChild(src.removeChild(src.firstChild))
  }
}

function sortUnorderedList(element_id, direction){
  var table = document.getElementById(element_id);
  var rows,i,tmp;

  // get the rows in the order as they are
  rows = table.rows;
  i = rows.length - 1;

  // tmp must be a node for this highly simplified stuff to work
  tmp = document.createElement("getoffmylawn");

  // do a simple Bubble sort (sorts lexically, maybe not what you want!)
  // Assumes things to sort are in the first cell, adjust if necessary
  for(; i > 0; i--){
    for(j = 0;j < i; j++){
      if(direction === false){
        if(rows[j].firstChild.firstChild.textContent < rows[j+1].firstChild.firstChild.textContent){
          copyElements (tmp , rows[j]);
          copyElements (rows[j]   , rows[j+1]);
          copyElements (rows[j+1] , tmp);
        }
      }
      else{
        if(rows[j].firstChild.firstChild.textContent > rows[j+1].firstChild.firstChild.textContent){
          copyElements ( tmp , rows[j]);
          copyElements (rows[j]   , rows[j+1]);
          copyElements (rows[j+1] , tmp);
        }      
      }
    }
  }

}

window.onload = function () {
    var desc = false;
    document.getElementById("Order").onclick = function () {
        sortUnorderedList("FileList", desc);
        desc = !desc;
        return false;
    };
};
</script>
</head>
<body>
<table id="FileList">
<tr><td><a href="a">Foo</a></td></tr>
<tr><td><a href="b">Bar</a></td></tr>
<tr><td><a href="c">Foobar</a></td></tr>
<tr><td><a href="d">Something</a></td></tr>
<tr><td><a href="e">Anything</a></td></tr>
<tr><td><a href="f">Somehwere</a></td></tr>
<tr><td><a href="g">elsewhere</a></td></tr>
<tr><td><a href="h">completely lost</a></td></tr>
</table>
<button id="Order">Sort</button>
</body>
</html>
```

If you think the order is wrong you have found out what "lexical order" actually means.

Comment: Thanks. Does not work because the list is generated by another command.

Comment: It does not matter if the list is generated by another command. The single difference is that I used a table instead of the unordered list of yours. That's all. Just exchange `table.rows` with `table.getElementsByTagName("li")`, make an `ul` out of the `table` and `li`'s out of the rows. Works like a charm. If it still doesn't work you have to post a complete HTML file, reduced to the bare minimum where the error occurs. Otherwise we have to wait for my crystal-ball to return from its bicentennial maintenance and polish.

Comment: Thanks, is working. sorry because I did not know much about programming, I am that I Am editing my blog.

Comment: I'm sorry, for bothering you again, but is that your code has a bug, it only organizes the names, but the link remains in the same position.
http://jmsprox.blogspot.com/p/indice.html

Comment: Although a rare thing but my code has no bug, it works *as intended*. If you want to move more then just the text inside you have to actually do it, e.g. by the method describe here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3066427/copy-all-childnodes-to-an-other-element-in-javascript-native-way. If you still want me to update my example with every cell being a link please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

To work in Internet Explorer and Firefox, I replaced:

`innerText` to `textContent`